# An image contains certain image java

Tags: java, bufferedimage

I have two buffered images and I want to check whether there is a **part** in Image 1 that is exactly the same as Image 2.

```
BufferedImage image1 = ......;
BufferedImage image2 = ......;
if(image1.contains(image2))  //I'm looking for method like contains
{
     //do some work.
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please be clear in what you want and what you have tired so far. Stack Overflow is not the best place to ask recommendations.

Comment: I didn't asked for recommendation. I had a problem and asked for it's solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[JavaCV](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv) is a good choice for image manipuation in Java. JavaCV is an OpenCV wrapper that contains tons of methods for image processing.

Comment: This is likely a very good library, and as such, this is probably a good answer, except for one thing: can you post an example of how you would do this using that library? As it is, this answer is still a little incomplete.